# useReducer behaving oddly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've run into a bit of a snag while trying to learn the `useReducer` hook. Previously i had been using `useState` to track state for input fields and validity of the input, i know a bit of the code here is redundant, however i'm doing it this way just to challenge myself and really try to nail down an understanding of this hook. Heres my problem though:

In the below code block, all of my handlers are working except for `validatePasswordHandler`.When numbers are used, the `console.logs` i have (**in both the handler function and the reducer function**) evaluate to `true` using the same logic as is used in the `dispatch` function, but still the state remains `false`. When letters are used, the `console.logs` (**within both handler, and reducer functions**) evaluate to `false` and the state remains false.

I want to base my `isFormValid` boolean on whether or not both `emailIsValid` and `passwordIsValid` are true. (For now, ignore the `isFormValid` as there is no handler for it yet.)

Added Screenshots of the console logs I made in the reducer function for the
passwordIsValid
[With Letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N8mp.png) --- [With Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qphb9.png)

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'entered_email':
      return { ...state, enteredEmail: action.payload };
    case 'isEmailValid':
      return { ...state, emailIsValid: action.isEmailValid };
    case 'entered_password':
      return { ...state, enteredPassword: action.payload };
    case 'passwordIsValid':
      return { ...state, passwordIsValid: action.isPasswordValid };
    case 'formIsValid':
      return { ...state, formIsValid: action.isFormValid };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const Login = (props) => {

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    enteredEmail: '',
    emailIsValid: null,
    enteredPassword: '',
    passwordIsValid: null,
    formIsValid: null,
  });

  const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'entered_email', payload: event.target.value });

    // setEnteredEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'entered_password', payload: event.target.value });
  };

  const validateEmailHandler = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'isEmailValid',
      isEmailValid: state.enteredEmail.includes('@'),
    });
  };

  const validatePasswordHandler = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'passwordIsValid',
      isPasswordValid: state.enteredPassword.length >= 6,
    });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onLogin(state.enteredEmail, state.enteredPassword);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.login}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            state.emailIsValid === false ? classes.invalid : ''
          }`}>
          <label htmlFor='email'>E-Mail</label>
          <input
            type='email'
            id='email'
            value={state.enteredEmail}
            onChange={emailChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validateEmailHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            state.passwordIsValid === false ? classes.invalid : ''
          }`}>
          <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
          <input
            type='password'
            id='password'
            value={state.enteredPassword}
            onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validatePasswordHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button
            type='submit'
            className={classes.btn}
            disabled={state.formIsValid === true ? false : true}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

From handler Func

```
const validatePasswordHandler = () => {
    console.log('from handler func func password:', state.enteredPassword);
    console.log(
      'from handler func password length:',
      state.enteredPassword.length
    );
    console.log(
      'from handler func typeof password:',
      typeof state.enteredPassword
    );
    console.log(
      'from handler func password greater than 6?:',
      state.enteredPassword.length > 6
    );
    dispatch({
      type: 'passwordIsValid',
      isPasswordValid: state.enteredPassword.length >= 6,
    });
  };
```

From reducer func

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'entered_email':
      return { ...state, enteredEmail: action.payload };
    case 'isEmailValid':
      return { ...state, emailIsValid: action.isEmailValid };
    case 'entered_password':
      return { ...state, enteredPassword: action.payload };
    case 'passwordIsValid':
      console.log('from reducer func password:', state.enteredPassword);
      console.log(
        'from reducer func password length:',
        state.enteredPassword.length
      );
      console.log(
        'from reducer func typeof password:',
        typeof state.enteredPassword
      );
      console.log(
        'from reducer func password greater than 6?:',
        state.enteredPassword.length > 6
      );
      return { ...state, passwordIsValid: action.isPasswordValid };
    case 'formIsValid':
      return { ...state, formIsValid: action.isFormValid };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};
```

Comment: The code seems to be working as expected. Can you please include the console.logs that you mention to see where and how exactly they produce the output we see in the screenshots?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I've edited the code to include blocks with the console logs that i specified in the screenshots. Essentially what i had before.
However, I believe i figured out my problem. According to the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer): 
"This is because states behaves like a snapshot. Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the state JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler.

If you need to guess the next state value, you can calculate it manually by calling the reducer yourself:"

Comment: `state.enteredPassword > 6` -- do you mean to be checking the length?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thats correct. I want that evaluation of that expression to determine validity, true or false, and then to then be passed to passwordIsValid

Comment: Okay; right now it's a numerical comparison. I don't know which you want, so I'm pointing out that you're not checking the length.

Comment: @DaveNewton, apologies, youre correct, I had to rewrite the console logs to add them in and missed the length property, but i assure you it was included when the taking the screenshots, in any case, ill edit the block to be correct. Thank you.